# Css Horizontal Float right to left

Tags: html, css, containers, floating

I want to have two divs like this:

```
.intro-body-left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 40%;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.intro-body-right {
    float: right;
    width: 59%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
   <div class="container">  
    <div id="intro">
        <div class="intro-header">
        </div>
        <a class="none" href="http://www...">
        <div class="intro-body-left animated fadeInLeft">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="intro-body-right animated fadeInRight">
            <p> some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I'd like to have the right container floating under the left one.
So the right Container should stay right but all content witch is under the left container should be under the left div. So The right div is meant to have a different thickness there.

Comment: just for reference, you should probably add the html code in here as well, as SO questions should be self sufficient should the links not be functional in the future.

Comment: Don't float the right div. Sacrifice the round corners.

Comment: Sorry for my Mistakes. I'm new here.

Comment: But here is my HTML code 

<div class="container"> 
 <div id="intro">
  <div class="intro-header">
   <h1></h1>
  </div>
  <a class="none" href="http://www...">
  <div class="intro-body-left animated fadeInLeft">
   <h1 style="text-align: center">&Uumlber </h1>
   <p>some text</p>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="intro-body-right animated fadeInRight">
   <h1 style="text-align: center">News </h1>
   <p> some text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Do you want the text to continue in the longer section below or do you want text at the width of the top right column width when it goes further down?

Comment: I want the text to continue in the longer section below. Like: http://puu.sh/l10dx/a68020cfc5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css to:

```
.intro-body-left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 40%;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.intro-body-right {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one (very simple) way to do it.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69hdLvch/

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top </div>
<div class="two">Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:20px transparent;
    background:#f00;
    position:absolute;
}

.two
{
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
    background:#00f;
    padding-left:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this work:

```
.intro-body-left {
     position : absolute;
     top: 40px;
     width: 40%;
     left : 0
     margin : 10px ; // for add space between 2 columns
     border-color: #ccc;
     border-radius: 15px;
     background-color: #f8f8f8;
     border: 1px solid;
 }
.intro-body-right {
   position : relative;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 40px;
   border-color: #ccc;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
   border: 1px solid;
  }
```